# can't playback videos from host

Tags: html5-video, web-hosting

I have `Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9 for Microsoft Windows` host. I tried to play some short video using several solution including: `camtasia`, `videojs` and `google youplay`. but all of them can't play back my video on host; I mean it's play and show on local and everythings is ok on local.
I using asp.net 4.5 on local and asp.net 4.0 on remote host.

I downloaded test video on [videojs](http://videojs.com/) and upload it to my host, but I confuse that there is nothing play from only my windows host. Are there any tip for playback video from windows host?

Comment: "***Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9 for Microsoft Windows***", you're on the wrong path, twice... use `cpanel/virtualmin` and `centos/debian`, and you'll learn something.

Comment: Please do not judge with prejudice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `Mitesh Gangaramani`for answering but there is no content as `video/mp4` so I had to deeper search and find an guaranteed solution for this problem. 
Just go to `web.config` and add these tags between `<configuration></configuration>` tag:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"></mimeMap>
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v"></mimeMap>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Then save and upload it to your `httpdocs`. I hope I could help who people had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the video type, control panel should have proper MIME type added.

1. Log into your Control Panel.
2. Under the **Domains** tab, click on **your domain name**.
3. Navigate on **Websites & Domains** tab.
4. Click on **Show Advanced Operations**.
5. Click on the **Virtual Directories** icon.
6. Navigate on **Mime Types** tab.
7. Click the **Add Mime Type** icon.
8. Enter the file extension and Content.
   example: 
   **Extension:**  .m4v
   **Content:**  video/mp4
9. Click **OK**.